# $routeProvider with templateURL not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view, route-provider

I am using $routeProvider in AngularJS with templateURl and my problem is that nothing happened, nothing shows on console and network tabs on dev tools (Chrome or Firefox). If i use template it works.

Bellow follows the hmtl and js files.

**mainPainelAdmin.html** (dir: view/admin/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adminCondominio">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Condomínio Ilha de Bari - Painel Administrador</title>

        <!-- Font Awesome CSS available via CDN; version 4.3.0 used here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">

        <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 0.10 used here -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/controllers/admin/mainPainelAdmin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/controllers/admin/menuPainelAdmin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/controllers/admin/mainAdmin.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/admin/mainPainelAdmin.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/admin/menuPainelAdmin.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainPainelAdminCtrl">
            <md-content>
                <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
                        <md-icon class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                    <h2>
                        <span>Condomínio Ilha de Bari - Administrador</span>
                    </h2>
                    <span flex></span>
                    <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" aria-label="Sair" style="padding-right: 5%" ng-click="logOff()">
                        <md-icon class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg" style="color: white; padding-left: 50%"> Sair </md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </md-toolbar>
                <section layout="row" flex ng-controller="MenuPainelAdmin">
                    <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="true">
                        <md-list>
                            <md-list-item class="mouseOver" ng-repeat="item in menuItens">
                                <p class="menuItemBotao {{item.icon}}" ng-click="go(item.ref)"> {{ item.name }} </p>
                            </md-list-item>
                        </md-list>
                    </md-sidenav>
                    <md-content flex layout-padding>
                        <div layout="column" layout-fill layout-align="top center">
                            <div ng-view></div>
                        </div>
                        <div flex></div>
                    </md-content>
                </section>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js** (dir: js/)

```
var app = angular.module('adminCondominio',['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);
```

**menuPainelAdmin.js** (dir: js/controllers/admin/)

```
app.controller('MenuPainelAdmin', function($scope, $location){
   $scope.menuItens = [
       {name: 'Início', icon:'fa fa-home fa-lg', ref:'home'},
       {name: 'Administração', icon:'fa fa-briefcase fa-lg', ref:'admin'},
       {name: 'Configurações', icon:'fa fa-cogs fa-lg', ref:'configs'}
   ];

   $scope.go = function ( path ) {
       $location.path( path );
   };
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateURL: 'inicioAdmin.html',
            controller: 'MainAdmin'
        })
        .when('/admin', {
            templateURL: 'administracaoAdmin.html'
        })
        .when('/configs', {
            templateURL: 'configuracaoAdmin.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

**mainAdmin.js** (dir: js/controllers/admin/)

```
app.controller('MainAdmin', function($scope){
    $scope.message="testeeeeee"
});
```

**inicioAdmin.html** (dir: view/admin/)

```
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

templateURL should be templateUrl in your route configurations.

`{templateUrl: 'some/page.html'}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need a controller for each view:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateURL: 'inicioAdmin.html',
        controller: 'MainAdmin'
    })
    .when('/admin', {
        templateURL: 'administracaoAdmin.html',
        controller: 'AdminController'
    })
    .when('/configs', {
        templateURL: 'configuracaoAdmin.html'
        controller: 'ConfigController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
```

And then ofcourse create those controllers

Comment: I've just made with one controller to see if it works. But I've tried with all controllers created.

Comment: And as I said, if I use template instead of templateURL, it works.

Answer (score 1):

As well as RVandersteen's answer, your paths are also wrong.

You said the inicioAdmin.html was in the directory `view/admin/`, so your route needs this information:

```
.when('/home', {
    templateURL: '/view/admin/inicioAdmin.html',
    controller: 'MainAdmin'
})
```

Don't forget the leading `/`

Comment: Even if the html are in the same directory?
I've changed the templateURL as you said but still not working.

Comment: I think so yes.  You are not referencing the view from mainPainelAdmin.html.  You referencing it from the route, which does not know about mainPainelAdmin.html.  You can try it and see.  Whatever works.

Answer (score -1):

some of the latest version of angularjs cdn is not being supported by chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
```

use this version `angularjs cdn` and work on Mozilla Firefox browser

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>